# Algorithm to divide an area so each given point is centered within its plot

Tags: algorithm, graphics

Suppose you have the location of n points. You want to subdivide the canvas so that each point lies within its own division, roughly in the center.

I've heard the algorithm goes something like this: "Siultaneously draw circles eminating from each point. When they touch another point's circle, the point(s) of contact/intersection are drawn to the canvas and the circles continue to grow. Eventually, these newly drawn dots become the border lines."

[image: given green dots and blue generated lines]

What is this algorithm called? I'd love to find an animation of it. Is there another algorithm that results in the same divisions?

Also, how would you code this? Java, python or C# preferable, but pseudocode or any other language is fine.

Comment: Looks like a [Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram). See [this app](http://alexbeutel.com/webgl/voronoi.html).

Comment: I knew someone here would know what it's called. Thanks! It is indeed a voronoi diagram. I wish I could mark this as an answer as I'll likely be able to find some pseudocode now that I know the name.

Comment: Also look at Delauney Triangulation, the complement problem which yields an efficient Voronoi algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partitioning a plane into regions based on set of points like you've drawn is known as Voronoi diagram. There are two popular algorithms for generating them

1. [Fortune's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune%27s_algorithm)

   A sweepline algorithm that builds the regions as sweep line moves across the dataset and is O(n log n) time and O(n) space
2. [Lloyd's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd%27s_algorithm)

   An iterative algorithm taht is similar to k-means but applies to continuous geometric regions.

If you already have a Delaunay triangulation of your points then you can compute the Vonoroi diagram (since they are duals) using the [Bowyer–Watson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowyer%E2%80%93Watson_algorithm) algorithm

Comment: Thanks to your answer and the comments to my original question, I was able to write a simple voronoi diagram algorithm to generate the graph I needed: 

http://s2.postimg.org/9yf69or7t/results.png